# Does classification of 1-manifolds with boundary give induced orientation of image of closed interval under a smooth immersion?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, derivatives, differential-geometry, manifolds

My book is An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu. Pictured below is the last example from Section 22, Manifolds with Boundary.

[image]

I have been trying to wrap my head around this for about 2 hours (3.5 hours, if you include the 1.5 hours spent on [the other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3143428/what-is-the-induced-orientation-on-a-1-manifold-with-boundary-that-is-the-image)).

**An alternative way** I approach the example: [classification of smooth 1-manifolds with boundary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4Htr.png)

1. Does the [classification of smooth 1-manifolds with boundary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4Htr.png) imply $C = c[a,b]$ and $[a,b]$ are diffeomorphic to $[0,1]$ and thus diffeomorphic to each other and thus $\partial C$ is diffeomorphic to $\partial [a,b] = \{a,b\}$, and $C^o$ is diffeomorphic to $(a,b)$?
2. Must $c$ be an embedding and in particular $c$ is injective?

**Update**: The [classification theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4Htr.png) assumes nonempty boundary. L[et's do so as well otherwise the example is wrong.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220878/a-manifold-with-boundary-has-dimension-at-least-1-if-it-has-a-dimension-and-if) Also see [here for the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3269469/what-is-the-induced-orientation-on-a-1-manifold-with-non-empty-boundary-that-is) but not specifically to do with the classification theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that the classification does not imply that $C$ and $[a, b]$ are diffeomorphic. It may very well be that $C$ is diffeomorphic to a circle, and that $c$ winds the interval $[a, b]$ 3.5 times around it. (The minute hand of the clock was giving you a hint.)

But *assuming* that $C$ has nonempty boundary, it follows indeed that the immersion $c$ is injective (i.e. is an embedding), as shown in a linked question:
[Is a smooth immersion $c: [a,b] \to M$ injective if its image is a 1-manifold with non-empty boundary?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3269469)

In particular, the boundary of $C$ has cardinality $2$ and equals $\{ c(a), c(b) \}$.

Comment: [LOL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mht35L7R65k). Thanks

Comment: punctured dusk, actually, do you or do you not assume $C$ is a 1-submanifold with boundary, namely with non-empty boundary of $M$? I'm just checking to see if this still makes sense if $C$ has some arbitrary differentiable structure that isn't really related to $M$ or something.

Comment: I do assume $C$ is a submanifold, if only to define the differentiable structure of $C$. I can't otherwise see a canonical way to give $C$ a differentiable structure. Then again, I think that the boundary of a $C^1$-variety can be defined topologically. If this is true, then a posteriori it doesn't matter which $C^1$-structure we give $C$, as long as we don't change the topology.

Comment: punctured dusk, thanks! You can answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3313881/is-image-is-1-manifold-with-non-empty-boundary-understood-as-image-is-1-subma) if you want.

Comment: Bart Michels, is $c$ a local diffeomorphism onto image? See OP's 2 other posts: [Surjective immersions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3301261/immersions-whose-images-are-actually-submanifolds-or-surjective-immersions-i) and [local diffeomorphism onto image](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3298630/what-is-are-the-definitions-of-local-diffeomorphism-onto-image)

Comment: @BCLC Yes, an immersion (that is, a differentiable map with everywhere injective differential) is locally a diffeomorphism onto (local) image.

Comment: i know immersion is equivalent to local embedding aka local-(diffeomorphism onto image), but i'm wondering: is this $c$ in particular is a (local difeomorphism)-onto image? the latter concept of LDOI (as in (LD)-OI) is stronger than immersion (as in L-(DOI)). it's proven that an immersion between manifolds whose image is not merely an immersed submanifold but actually a regular/embedded submanifold is a (local diffeomorphism)-onto image.  i guess the previous sentence would apply to manifolds with boundary too.

Comment: @BCLC In any case, in the one-dimensional case the image of a smooth immersion is a smooth submanifold (with or without boundary) of the target. And then there is no ambiguity in LDOI.

Comment: Bart Michels, do you mean that in 1 - the condition that the image of $c$ is reg/emb submanifold with boundary (with non-empty boundary), the only assumption is the non-empty boundary because the image is already reg/emb submanifold with boundary and 2 - if so, then this is because the domain of $c$ is 1-dimensional?

Comment: @BCLC Yes, the fact that the map is an immersion implies that the image is a smooth submanifold with boundary, and this is because *both* domain and target manifold are 1-dimensional. (It would not be always true if only the domain is 1-dim.) So that, as you say, the only extra condition you need is that the image has nonempty boundary.

Comment: thanks Bart Michels!