# Is a smooth immersion $c: [a,b] \to M$ injective if its image is a 1-manifold with non-empty boundary?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, orientation

My book is An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu. Pictured below is the last example from Section 22, Manifolds with Boundary.

[image]

In this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3143428/what-is-the-induced-orientation-on-a-1-manifold-with-boundary-that-is-the-image), it is confirmed that the example is an error. Besides a few nitpicks such as $c(p)$ instead of $p$ or $c:[a,b] \to M$ versus restricted range $c$ given by $\tilde{c}:[a,b] \to C$, a counterexample given was $c:[0,2\pi] \to \mathbb R^2$, $c(t)=(\cos t, \sin t)$ (I guess you can do $e^{it}$ and $\mathbb C$ if you like). However, the example is true if $c$ were injective by [Exercise 11.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lF45U.png) extended from manifolds to manifolds with boundary (extension is hopefully possible because "[Most of the concepts introduced for a manifold extend word for word to a manifold with boundary...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220878/a-manifold-with-boundary-has-dimension-at-least-1-if-it-has-a-dimension-and-if)").

It was pointed out by quarague in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3269386/what-is-the-induced-orientation-on-a-1-manifold-with-boundary-that-is-the-image)'s comments that another condition that might make the example true is to assume the image, which is given to be 1-manifold with boundary, is [additionally assumed to have non-empty boundary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220878/a-manifold-with-boundary-has-dimension-at-least-1-if-it-has-a-dimension-and-if). As it turns out, this might actually imply $c$ injective.

1. Is it true that $c$ would be injective?
2. If yes to (1), then why?
3. If no to (1), then is the example still true even though $c$ is not injective?
4. If no to (1) and yes to (3), then why?
5. If no to (1) and no to (3), then why?

Note: Maybe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3145935/does-classification-of-1-manifolds-with-boundary-give-induced-orientation-of-ima) is now relevant.

- Update: I think it is relevant because of the word ["nonempty" in the classification theorem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4Htr.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The only $1$-manifolds, up to diffeomorphism, are $S^1, \mathbb R$, $[0, 1]$ and $[0, 1)$.

**Fact.** For $X$ $1$-dimensional and $Y$ $1$-dimensional, with $Y$ not diffeomorphic to $S^1$, a smooth immersion $c : X \to Y$ is injective.

*Proof.* Take a point $t \in X$ such that $c(t)$ equals some $c(s)$ with $s \neq t$. Because $c$ is an immersion, $c$ is approximately linear around $t$, so there exists $s \in X$ and a segment $[t, s] \subset X$ such that $c(s) = c(t)$ and such that $c$ is injective on $[t, s)$. Here, by segment, I mean a diffeomorphism on its image $\phi : [p, q] \to X$ with $\phi(p) = t$, $\phi(q) = s$. Now $c \circ \phi$ is a smooth immersion $[p, q] \to \mathbb R$ with $\phi(p) = \phi(q)$. By the mean value theorem, its derivative vanishes somewhere. A contradiction. $\square$

To prove that classification, here's a hint: consider a maximal chart $(0,1) \to X$. Use maximality to prove that its image misses at most $2$ points of $X$.

Comment: Thanks. I think you can answer here [too](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3145935/does-classification-of-1-manifolds-with-boundary-give-induced-orientation-of-ima). Is there a way to do this without classification theorem because classification theorem isn't given in this book?

Comment: Yes, in the sense that the only part of the classification that we need for the original question, is that a $1$-manifold with nonempty boundary can be embedded in $\mathbb R$. (The part you cite in the other answer.)

Comment: Nice. Something I'll check out later. Thanks!

Comment: I rejected your edit suggestion: we only need $Y$ to be not diffeomorphic to $S^1$, because we only need $Y$ to be embeddable in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: You write "not not". What does that mean?

Comment: It was a typo, thanks.

Comment: punctured dusk, actually, do you or do you not assume $C$ is a 1-submanifold with boundary, namely with non-empty boundary of $M$? I'm just checking to see if this still makes sense if $C$ has some arbitrary differentiable structure that isn't really related to $M$ or something.